# I am not able to create multiple files to store these values

Tags: java

// I have to implement queing theory in this problem. I have to generate a random value and store the values in a file. I am trying to create multiple files to store the values of different ranges. But I am not able to. I am only able to create the first file that is VariableInputRate.txt and not the other file. I need help to create the other file as well. Otherwise is there any way where I can combine the two values and save it in a single file.
Thanks

```
    String path1 = "c://VariableInputRate(0-10).txt";  

     for(int i = 0 ; i < x/10 ; i ++ )
     {     
         y= Math.random();                  //call a random number generator  
                                            //to generate a random number between 0 and 1
         if(y <= in_rate1 /(in_rate1 + out_rate))
         {
             if(pkt_in_q < n)
                 pkt_in_q ++;
             else
                 pkt_dropped ++;
         }
         else
         {
             if(pkt_in_q > 0)
                  pkt_in_q --;
         }    



         File file = new File(path1);
         try {
             file.createNewFile();
             } 
         catch (IOException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
             }

         try {
             FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
             BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
             bw.write("For Event " + (i+1) +" we get: ");
             //bw.newLine();
             bw.write("No. of packets in the queue = " + pkt_in_q +" and no. of packets dropped = "+ pkt_dropped);
             bw.newLine();
             bw.flush();
             bw.close();
             fw.close();
             } 
         catch (IOException e) 
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     System.out.println("Please take at output 1.");

     String path2 = "c://VariableInputRate(10-70).txt";  //Depends on which disk you are using, e.g. C,D,E,F disk

     for( int i=j/10 ; i < k/70 ; i ++ )
     {     
         y= Math.random();                  //call a random number generator  
                                            //to generate a random number between 0 and 1
         if(y <= in_rate2 /(in_rate2 + out_rate))
         {
             if(pkt_in_q < n)
                 pkt_in_q ++;
             else
                 pkt_dropped ++;
         }
         else
         {
             if(pkt_in_q > 0)
                  pkt_in_q --;
         }    



         File file = new File(path2);
         try {
             file.createNewFile();
             } 
         catch (IOException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
             }

         try {
             FileWriter fw2 = new FileWriter(file, true);
             BufferedWriter bw2 = new BufferedWriter(fw2);
             bw2.write("For Event " + (i+1) +" we get: ");
             //bw.newLine();
             bw2.write("No. of packets in the queue = " + pkt_in_q +" and no. of packets dropped = "+ pkt_dropped);
             bw2.newLine();
             bw2.flush();
             bw2.close();
             fw2.close();
             } 
         catch (IOException e) 
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     System.out.println("Please take at output 2.");
```

Comment: What happens when you try? What error do you get?

Comment: Q: Are you sure your slashes are correct?  SUGGESTED CHANGE: ` String path1 = "c:\\VariableInputRate(0-10).txt";`

Comment: Yes your path does not look correct. I also have a suggestion for file manipulation. I use apache commons file utility. This library has a lot of methods to make your life easy which manipulating files. Give it a go. It would also help to provide us with a stack trace if your getting an exception.

Answer (score 0):

First can you try to change `/` slashes to `\` or `\\`? Second why do you create always new File in loop? Because first only have one path. In loop many time created `File file = new File(path1);`.

I think better declare new File a created it in outside a loop. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Combining them in a single file should be easy:

```
// Warning: code written of my mind, might not compile!
// imports left out

public class Whatever {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String path=System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\output.txt");
        File f=new File(path);
        OutputStream os=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));

        // perform whatever computations you want here
        String s1=Foo.bar();
        os.write(s1.getBytes("UTF-8");

        String s2=Bar.foo();
        os.write(s2.getBytes("UTF-8");

        os.close();
    }

}
```